# k6 custom parameter on run line

Tags: k6

How can I add a `--testenv test12` custom parameter to my tests:

```
k6 --out cvs=results.csv run --vus 60 --duration 2m --testenv test12 ./mass-login.js
```

In k6s default function the variable is defined:

```
export default function () {
  :  
  //const testenvs = ['test12', 'test1', 'test4', 'qa-04', 'prod'];
  const testenvs = ['qa-04'];
```

Current hack is to have different js files, except for 1 line fully redundant.

Comment: What is the `--testenv` parameter? Are you asking how to set environment variables and read those?

Comment: correct @knittl a custom variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an [environment variable](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables/):

```
k6 -e testenv=test12 ./your_script.js
```

… and then read it in your test:

```
const testenv = __ENV.testenv;
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I was unable to find this on their web page